# Common functions in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some common functions that I've written that I'm currently copying in to each of my controllers. An example is a method that puts together my main navigation - I'm currently copying it in to each and every one or my controllers.

Is there any way I can put these common functions somewhere so I don't have to repeat the same code in each controller?

I thought creating core classes in the user guide would be it but that only seems to be to extend the current core

Comment: That is why [**Helpers**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html) are for.

Comment: If you extend the core controller every controllers will have access to his methods.

Comment: Oh really? I read the Helpers page in the user guide. I don't see any mention of creating your own helpers there...only using existing ones and extending existing ones....if that's the case then I'll create my own...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole bunch of ways to do this:

1. Like Rikesh said, use [Helpers](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html).
2. If you have a whole bunch of such functions, structure them into [Libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Usually in CI, helpers are just files with a bunch of "helper" functions. Libraries are better organized into classes. Personally, I would create a custom lib called `Common` or maybe specialize them further like a `Nav Lib` or so. Thats why I love CI its so simple yet flexible!

Comment: Thanks I'm going to look in to creating a Common library and then autoload this